# How to change number of bins in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bins

I have the following code:

```
ax1.hist(true_time, bins=500, edgecolor="none")
ax2.hist(true_time_2, bins=500, edgecolor="none")
```

I expected that it would give me two hists with the same number of bins, but it wouldn't:
[image]

How to do it correctly?

Comment: The second one looks like it has 500 bins. The first doesn't, but you can't be sure: maybe `true_time` just takes a very small set of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some distant outlier in true_time, it may be that the bins were made just really really big to include it.

Comment: How to overcome it?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich you would have to sort `true_time` and see if there were some values in there that were several orders of magnitude greater than 160,000. But I think this answer should have been a comment because it's a bit of a stab in the dark, no?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of values after 160,000.

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich then the stab in the dark is probably correct! :) You haven't shown your supporting code, but basically there probably are 500 bins, but each has to span ~20,000 and you've probably restricted the x axis range.